Same Azure Release Task in Two Different Release Pipelines Behave Differently git clone *> $null
I have two different Azure Releases that each have the exact same task that includes cloning a repo, except for one difference.  I have to send the output to null in one case and not in the other, both will fail with errors if each is done the other way.  Important note: both of these releases target the exact same servers (so it's not different servers).  It seems it must be a difference in how the pipeline interprets the results.
git clone --branch $branch $connectString

vs
git clone --branch $branch $connectString *> $null

When the one is sent to null, all I get back is "PowerShell exited with code '1'."
When the other is not sent to null, I see the repo get cloned (all in red font) then the pipeline exits without an error message.
Cloning into 'repo'...
Updating files:  13% (393/2903)
...
Updating files: 100% (2903/2903)
Updating files: 100% (2903/2903), done.

I've already looked into why this happens and addressed it by adding *> null.
My question is what could be the difference between these two Azure Releases.  Is there a setting that controls how output is interpreted?

Are the two release pipelines in the same project in Azure DevOps? Do they use the same agents to run the jobs? If you remove "*> $null" from the second pipeline, does it can work? The '$null' is a reserved key in many script languages, what reason does cause you must define the variable name as it?

Same project.  Same agent.  Same server.  As I said in the question the reverse of either does not work.  The language is Powershell.  The very point is to send it to the reserved $null.

Try to send the output to a variable with a another name like as the following.  $gitCloneOutput = git clone --branch $branch $connectString  In addition, did you try the two commands on your local machine, and does the issue also exist? @AdamWinter
